# Apple ID two-factor authentication in CI process

Tags: continuous-integration, two-factor-authentication

Apple starting February 27, 2019 [will require two-factor authentication](https://appleinsider.com/articles/19/02/13/apple-to-require-two-factor-authentication-for-developer-accounts):

> In an effort to keep your account more secure, two-factor
>   authentication will be required to sign in to your Apple Developer
>   account and Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles starting February 27,
>   2019.

We use several organisations and team agents have separate accounts and use them in CI. Does anyone have ideas how to integrate two-factor authentication into CI process?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [official two-factor](https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/#two-step-or-two-factor-auth) docs for more information on how to setup two-step on CI system. You'll have to authenticate on your local machine to get a session cookie, which you then transfer to your CI.